# MS Access - Create a query to replace a string only if certain criteria is met

Tags: ms-access

I should probably start that I am very new to MS Access and in fact I am currently in the process of learning how to work with it. That said I stumbled upon a situation where after a long search on the internet I was still not able to find a solution.

What I am trying to do is create a MS Access query, which would go through the "Date" column and if we have a single "." to replace with "no". I would be really grateful if you can help me or at least give me a hint how can I achieve that. Thank you in advance!

I have tried with Replace(column,".","no"). However, this affects all dots and then the dates have "no" instead of a ".".

```css
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-0pky{border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>

Before the query:
```

```html
<table class="tg">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Name</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Date</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Quantity</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">John</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">10.10.2020</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Tom</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">05.05.2020</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Ben</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">02.02.2012</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Josh</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">.</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

After the query:

<table class="tg">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Name</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Date</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Quantity</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">John</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">10.10.2020</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Tom</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">05.05.2020</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Ben</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">02.02.2012</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Josh</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">No</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I dont really understand what you want. Please add some example of dates before and after. The HTML piece of code there doesnt help. You should show the data stored in the database and not how you output it afterwards with the applciation

Comment: @ThomasG I am sorry, I have added the table before and the result I want to achieve after creating the query. I hope that this time it would be more clear of my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly...

I assume that `.` (dot) is your regional date separator.

```
SELECT [Name], IIF(IsDate([Date]), [Date], "no") As [Expr1], Quantity
FROM YourTable;
```

I need to warn you: `Name` and `Date` are reserved words. Avoid of naming object (tables/fields) with that words. See: [Learn about Access reserved words and symbols](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2)

Comment: CASE WHEN is not valid MS Access SQL syntax. You should convert that to iif() or switch()

Comment: Thank you, @ThomasG. I've improved my answer.

Comment: Sorry, it took me some time to play with the code that you have provided. I noticed that you are using IsDate, but the column containing the dates is set as "Short Text". Thus from the microsoft documentation I found that `=IIf([CountryRegion]="Italy", "Italian", "Some other language")` However, when I change it to `SELECT Table1.[Name], [Date]=IIf([Date]=".","No",[Date]) AS Expr1, Table1.Quantity
FROM Table1;` I get -1 for the ones that do not match and 0 for the ones that match. I am a little bit confused why the output is the 0 and 1 instead of the date or the "no" value.

Comment: Please, check updated `select` statement. What is your date separator?

Comment: After playing a little bit with the code I found out that the following solution `SELECT Table1.Name, IIf([Date]=".","No",[Date]) AS Expr1, Table1.Quantity
FROM Table1;` is working. Furthermore, the article about the reserved words and symbols is quite useful! Thank you very much. I am really grateful for your help! (The date separator is ".".)